# Filter a query in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have the following query

```
select a.empid, a.age, a.city, b.name
  join supervisor b on a.supervisorid = b.empid
```

There is a chance that entries in "Supervisor" table may not be present in "Employee" table as an Employee
After forming the above query , i want to make "b.supervisorname" field as "null", if "b.supervisorid" not in "a.empid" column

EMPLOYEE TABLE:

> EMPID--AGE--CITY--SUPERVISOR
>
> 1--12--A--123
>
> 2--21--B--1
>
> 3--23--C--2

Supervisor Table:

> SUPERVISOR TABLE
>
> EMPID--NAME
>
> 123--ABC
>
> 1--EFG
>
> 2-HIJ

OUTPUT:

> EMPID--AGE--CITY--NAME
>
> 1--12--A--null
>
> 2--21--B--ABC
>
> 3--23--C--EFG

i dont want to use,

```
select a.empid, a.age, a.city, b.name
  from employee a
  join supervisor b on a.supervisorid =
                       (select empid
                          from supervisor
                         where empid in (select empid from employee))
```

as this kind of querying affects the performance

Is there any shortcut way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **ALWAYS** use explicit joins to avoid performance issues. And in general it helps to define a `FROM` clause in queries

The query below should work for you:

```
select
    e.empid,
    e.age,
    e.city,
    s.name
FROM
    employee e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        supervisor s
        on e.supervisor = s.empid
```

Comment: This is the right way, to be done! +1 deleting mine!

Comment: @OracleUser I certainly appreciate the +1 and comment thank you! Had you posted a LEFT JOIN first before me then I would have simply upvoted you :)